# Присвоение ID пользователю

Tags: c#, datagridview, users

подскажите кто разбирается в чем проблема, присваиваю ID пользователю в классе User, программно ID присваивается нормально, но как создаю нового происходит что-то неясное, у User ID через 1, у Awards следующее значение после 5 вообще 15, помогите пожалуйста, все перепробовал, очень буду благодарен.

ID в классе User:

```
private static int _uniqueId = 0;

    public User()
    {
        ID = _uniqueId;
        _uniqueId++;
    }
```

ID в классе Awards

```
private static int _uniqueId = 0;
    public Awards()
    {
        ID = _uniqueId;
        _uniqueId++;
    }
```

Создание объектов классов:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Emmy", Description = "Американская телевизионная премия" });
        _awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Grammy", Description = "Музыкальная премия Американской академии звукозаписи" });
        _awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Oskar", Description = "Премия Американской академии кинематографических искусств и наук" });
        _awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Tony", Description = "Театральная премия" });
        _awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Премия Дарвина", Description = "Неофициальная премия, присуждаемая комиссией людям лишившим себя наследства по своей глупости и неосторожности" });

        dgvAwards.DataSource = _awards;

        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Денис",
            LastName = "Евдокименко",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1996, 11, 07),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> { _awards[0], _awards[1], _awards[2], _awards[3], _awards[4] }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Виталий",
            LastName = "Астахов",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1993, 05, 01),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> {  }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Петр",
            LastName = "Василенко",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1995, 12, 12),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> {  }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Влад",
            LastName = "Акумов",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 04, 22),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> {  }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Семен",
            LastName = "Амелькин",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1998, 02, 19),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> {  }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Герман",
            LastName = "Алтуфьев",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(2004, 03, 18),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> {  }
        });
        _users.Add(new User()
        {
            Name = "Евгений",
            LastName = "Парфенов",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1994, 01, 01),
            Listawards = new List<Awards> { }
        });

        dgvUsers.DataSource = _users;
        dgvUsers.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dgvAwards.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
```

[image: ID пользователей]

[image: ID юзеров]

Answer (score 0):

У Вас поле _uniqueId статическое, в конструкторе оно увеличивается на 1.

Код

```
_awards.Add(new Awards() { Title = "Emmy", Description = "Американская телевизионная премия" });
```

автоматически добавляет объект класса в коллекцию, здесь все нормально.

Предполагаю, что где-то в коде Вы просто создаете объекты этих классов без добавления в коллекцию, то ID все-равно увеличивается.

Что-то типа:

```
Awards award = new Awards() { Title = "New", Description = "NewDescription" };
```

Думаю проблема заключается именно в этом.